# c# Add a multidimensional array to my list

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to make a list of positions in my 2d array grid in which the value of the grid is a certain number but I just can't seem to get the syntax of the code right

```
int[,] Field = new int[n,n];
List<int[,]> lijst = new List<int[,]>();
for (int p = 0; p < n; p++)
{
    for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
    {
        Field[p, q] = 0;
        lijst.Add(?????);
    }
}
```

I just can't seem to find what to type in the place of the ????
Because [p,q] doesn't seem to work and neither does (p,q)

EDIT:
Sorry Field is the name of the 2d array grid.

EDIT 2:
I'm setting all the values in my grid to 0, because if i want to read the grid i want to know where to place things, for example when it is 0 it is empty but when its a 1 or a 2 it gets a stone placed in it. and i want to write a methode that scans which places in the grid are empty so that it returns a list of places not the values

Comment: What is your expected output for a given `n`? What is the purpose of `Field`?

Comment: If you want `lijst` to be a list of row/col coordinate pairs, that's the wrong data type. You want `var coords = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();` Add coordinate pairs like so: `coords.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(p, q));` Or if you're in winforms or something where `Point` is defined, take TheGeneral's advice and use that.

Comment: or `List<Point>`

Comment: Why are you setting every value in `Field` to zero?

Comment: If you want to just add [p,q] to it then do it like this,`lijst.Add(new int[p,q]);`

Comment: @Michael OP wants "a list of positions in my 2d array grid". I think there's a missing `if` statement -- possibly that part hasn't been written yet either. You would be encoding that information as `a.GetLength(0)` and `a.GetLength(1)`, but I don't think that was your intent.

Comment: @all_commenters, i've put some edits in place, hopefully this is more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment i have found a little sneaky side step but i dont find it the best since i believe it should be able to do this direct but okay,
What i found is that if you store the p and q in a datastructure made for coordinates and you just list those coordinates you can retrieve them later by getting the place and their specifiek coordinates.

```
List<Plek> EmptyList()
    {
        List<Place> Pair = new List<Place>();

        for (int p = 0; p < n; p++)
        {
            for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
            {
                if (Field[p, q] == 0)
                {
                    Place pair = new Place(p, q);
                    Pair.Add(pair);
                }
            }
        }

        return Pair;

    }
```

The datastructure

```
class Place
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Place(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```